# VB.net Null reference on database connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I know I'm being an idiot here and I just can't work it out. But i'm trying to take some data back from a vb.net database. It's falling over with a Object reference not set to an instance of an object error. And before the code runs it's saying the variable is being used before it's set, but I can't see how. Code:

```
  Private taNotifications As dsDataTableAdapters.NotificationsTableAdapter = New dsDataTableAdapters.NotificationsTableAdapter 

   Dim notification As dsData.NotificationsDataTable = taNotifications.GetDataByClientID(userrow.UserID)

                If notification.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                    Dim notificationrow As dsData.NotificationsRow
                    Dim forwardURL As String = notificationrow.ForwardLocation

                End If
```

It falls over on the `Dim forwardURL As String = notificationrow.ForwardLocation`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have never instantiated the notificationRow inside the if statement. You've declared it, but it doesn't belong to anything. You need to make an assignment or loop through your rows before doing anything with this object:

```
Dim notificationrow As dsData.NotificationsRow ' this is not instantiated
Dim forwardURL As String = notificationrow.ForwardLocation
```

What you really want in this case is:

```
For Each notificationRow As dsData.NotificationRow In notification

    Dim forwardURL As String = notificationRow.ForwardLocation        
    ' Do Something

Next
```

If you only HAVE one row and you know you only have 1 or 0 rows then you could use your if statement by doing:

```
If notification.Rows.Count > 0 Then

    Dim notificationrow As dsData.NotificationsRow = _
        CType(notification.Rows(0), dsData.NotificationsRow)

    Dim forwardURL As String = notificationrow.ForwardLocation

End If
```

Edit: In the code above, I originally just had `notification.Rows(0)`. This will produce a DataRow object, but it will not be strongly typed. You need to perform the `CType` that I added in order to use the custom property `ForwardLocation`.

Answer (score 1):

You never set `notificationrow` to anything.  Did you mean to set it like this?

```
Dim notificationrow As dsData.NotificationsRow = CType(notification.Rows(0), dsData.NotificationsRow)
```